# Trying to include a form on another app's template with {% include %}, but getting "TemplateDoesNotExist"

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Currently, I can leave a comment about a post, but I have to go to a separate comment create page. I want to include the comment form right under the post in the group detail page. I have tried to use {% include %}, but it cant seem to find the form. This is probabaly because I am trying to render the form on a different app's template than where the form.py and comment_form.html are (I create the form and the template for the form in the 'comments' app, and I'm trying to include the form in the the 'groups' app on the detail page. here are the relevant files.

comments/forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)
```

comments/comment_form.html

```
<h2>this is the comment form</h2>
<form class="post-form" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

groups/views.detail :

```
def detail(request, group_id):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk= group_id)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(group__id = group_id)
    form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, 'groups/detail.html', {'group': group, 'posts':posts, 'form':form})
```

groups/detail.html:

```
{% include form %}
```

this is the url that takes care of creating a comment (comments/urls.py):

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'comments'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:post_id>/create/', views.create, name='create'),
    path('delete/<int:group_id>/<int:post_id>/<int:comment_id>', views.delete, name='delete'),
]
```

again, it can't find the template, probabaly because I have to make the 'groups' app aware of 'comment_form.html' 's existence. how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include `comments/comment_form.html` you should do:

```
{% include 'comments/comment_form.html' %}
```

Currently, you have `{% include form %}` which will use the variable `form` - that doesn't make sense, since `form` is a form instance `CommentForm()`, it is not a template name.

Comment: ok. However, the fields of the form (only 1 field in this case, 'body') aren't showing up, only the title and the submit button. so form.as_p isn't grabbing the required fields.

Comment: I can't spot any other issues. Perhaps the request is being handled by a different URL. You haven't shown your URL patterns or said which URL you are going to, so I can't tell.

Comment: You could also add `print(form)` to the view, which should include the `body` field. That woul narrow down whether the problem is in the view or template.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. currently, the form is showing with the body field, but when I submit it, the comments are not saving.

Comment: Your form is submitting to the current url `<form class="post-form" method="post">
`, and the `detail` view does not have any code to handle the form submission. That's really a separate issue from your `TemplateDoesNotExist` error, so it doesn't belong on this question.